# App Store review guidelines for purchasing subscriptions using Paypal

Tags: ios, paypal, app-store

I'd like to integrate payment for subscription to our services. Currently the website offers manually-renewable subscription for 6 or 12 months, and we take the payment by Credit Card (authorize.net payment gateway) or PayPal. As we'd like to offer the users to be able to renew subscriptions from our iOS app, too, I was thinking if I could integrate the Paypal and Authorize.net SDKs in our app instead of using in-app purchases.

Here are the points related to my question from the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies):

> 11.2. Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected
>
> 11.12. Apps offering subscriptions must do so using IAP, Apple will share the same 70/30 revenue split with developers for these purchases, as set forth in the Program License Agreement.
>
> 11.13. Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the App, such as a "buy" button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected.

The above points don't exactly answer my following question:

If I must use in-app purchases for subscription renewals, can I also provide users the options to pay via Paypal and Credit Card through my iOS app besides in-app purchases? Note that the "buy" button won't go to a *website* to purchase the subscription - I'll be integrating PayPal and Authorize.net SDKs to receive purchases from the app.

Comment: Is this still current information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple handles the payment options for you, you cannot offer your "own" payment providers for In-App Purchases. (You can, but your app will be rejected)

The official payment options vary on the user's country: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202631

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there are things happening in this space.
According to [recent news](https://appleinsider.com/articles/21/08/03/south-korean-legislation-could-force-external-payment-options-onto-app-store), apple is forced to allow external payments.

I don't know if it is already in effect in the guidelines of apple but I suspect it will be coming.